# Prove that the set of $\mathcal{L}$-terms has size $\max\{\aleph_0, \#\text{ of constant sym plus the $\#$ function sym}\}$.

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a first-order language.  Prove that the set of $\mathcal{L}$-terms has size $\max\{\aleph_0,\text{ the number of constant symbols plus the number of function symbols}\}$.

I know that the set of $\mathcal{L}$-terms is at least $\aleph_0$ because there are countably many variables.  I also know that, if the number of constants and function symbols is at most countable then there is at most countable many terms.

I am not sure how to deal with the following case: suppose there are $\beta$ many function and constant symbols where $\beta$ is an uncountable ordinal.  Would this mean that there would be at least $\aleph_0^\beta$ many terms?  I believe $\aleph_0^\beta$ is greater than $\beta$, so I must be getting something wrong.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Terms are made of *finitely* many symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exponentiation is all wrong. You need to think in terms of cardinals, not ordinals, and recall that terms are *finite* strings from the alphabet formed under certain rules.

**HINT:** Recall that for every infinite set $X$, we have $|X|=|X\times X|$, and therefore $|X|=|\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}X^n|$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: each term has only a finite length. For any $n$, $\lvert X^n\rvert\leq \lvert X\rvert + \aleph_0$.

Comment: Thanks.  Why did you add the "+ $\aleph_0$"?

Comment: @marienich: Because in the case $X$ is finite, the powers might grow, but not beyond $\aleph_0$.